# Can't save entity with composite key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I get an exception when I try to save entities when composite key is used. Here is the exception, models and repository I try to save to. Can anyone help?

> org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert
>   property value of type 'org.CheckType_$$_jvst96c_4' to required type
>   'int' for property 'checkType'; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type
>   'org.CheckType_$$_jvst96c_4' to required type 'int' for property
>   'checkType': PropertyEditor
>   [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomNumberEditor]
>   returned inappropriate value of type 'org.CheckType_$$_jvst96c_4'

```
@Entity
public class CheckType {
    @Id
    private int id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "checkType")
    private List<ClientCheck> checks;
    //getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class Offer {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "offerid")
    private Integer offerId;
    //...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "offer")
    private List<ClientCheck> clientCheckList;

    //getters and setters
}

@Entity
@IdClass(ClientCheckId.class)
public class ClientCheck {
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "offer_id", referencedColumnName = "offerid")
    private Offer offer;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "check_type_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private CheckType checkType;

    @Id
    private Date timestamp;

    private String result;
    //getters and setters
}

public class ClientCheckId implements Serializable {
    private int offer;
    private int checkType;
    private Date timestamp;

    //getters and setters
    //equals and hashCode
}

public interface ClientCheckRepo extends JpaRepository<ClientCheck, ClientCheckId> {
}
```

Comment: What is the context? How are you creating and saving this entity? Via an MVC request?

Comment: I don't know if context is important; I get a request on controller, make/save an offer, create time stamp, read check types and for each get a result of check and then save check with all the parameters set.

Comment: The context is important because the error 'org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException' suggests the issue is in binding of the request parameters. Can you post the relevant controller code.

Comment: The exception occurred when "clientCheckRepo.save(clientCheck)" in the controller is called. Now, that is in the service layer.

Comment: Your entity mapping seems valid (according to the JPA 2.1 spec). Perhaps a bug in Spring-Data? Are you using the latest version?

Comment: I use 1.10.6.RELEASE version (spring-data-jpa)which should be the latest